# how to get the images from device in android java application

Tags: android

In my application I want to upload the image.

For that I have to get images from gallery in android device.

How do I write code that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Raise an Intent with Action as `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and set the type to "`image/*`". This will start the photo picker Activity. When the user selects an image, you can use the `onActivityResult` callback to get the results.

Something like:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();

        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), chosenImageUri);
        }
}
```

Comment: hi samuh.by using this code i am getting image from media what's my problem is i need to store that image in remote server.i am converted mBitmap into bytearray when i try to send byte array it is shwoing 5 digit code i am feeling like it is address of the byte array .can you please help out from this problem

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: you are probably sending the HashCode of the byte array instead of the array elements.

Comment: in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/pictures/einstein3.jpg");
buf = new BufferedInputStream(in,2000);
System.out.println("1.................."+buf);
byte[] byteArray= new byte[buf.available()];
buf.read(byteArray);

now i am sending "byteArray" to server that is not sending only hashcode sending .can you suggest me where i made mistake

Comment: On Android 4.4 this now has unwanted behaviour (launch the recent documents screen). See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2507973/276949