# how to get bitmap uri in android mobile device using java

Tags: android

i am implemented this code image upload device only how can retrieve bitmap uri
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ACTIVITY_RESULT_IMAGE_SELECTED);

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent,Intent data, CharSequence Uri) 
 {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

     if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_RESULT_IMAGE_SELECTED)
     {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                     Uri uri = intent.getData();
                     Object mBitmap = MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT; //Media.//getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
                     //EditText images=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextImages);
                   //  mImageUploadAdapter.addImage(uri);
                    // mImageUploadGridView.invalidateViews();
             }
     } i am implementing this code
```

Comment: ...? I think you need to add some detail to your question. For example, what is your question?

Comment: I'm new to Android please forward solution

Comment: Agree with Jeff; please be clear when asking questions it will only help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intent.getData()` will return the URI of the Bitmap. If your question is about how you are to create a Bitmap Object from this URI you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227209/how-to-get-the-images-from-device-in-android-java-application/2229154#2229154).

Comment: ok ,its not working  just error display method getBitmap(ContentResolver, Uri) is undefined for the type MediaStore.Audio.Media   
thank you very much