# how do you pass images (bitmaps) between android activities using bundles?

Tags: android, image, bundle

Suppose I have an activity to select an image from the gallery, and retrieve it as a BitMap, just like the example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227209/how-to-get-the-images-from-device-in-android-java-application/2229154#2229154)

Now, I want to pass this BitMap to be used in an ImageView for another activity. I am aware bundles can be passed between activities, but how would I store this BitMap into the bundle?

or is there another approach I should take?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I would highly recommend a different approach.

It's possible if you REALLY want to do it, but it costs a lot of memory and is also slow. It might not work if you have an older phone and a big bitmap. You could just pass it as an extra, for example `intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)`. A Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you can put it in an extra. Likewise, a bundle has `putParcelable`.

If you want to pass it inbetween activities, I would store it in a file. That's more efficient, and less work for you. You can create private files in your data folder using MODE_PRIVATE that are not accessible to any other app.

Comment: what if I just passed the path of the image to the other activity?

Comment: Absolutely, that's perfect! I thought the Bitmap was temporarily created by your activity, that's why you had to pass it along. (If you DID create it like that, you may want to save it to your local folder and then reload it).

Comment: Btw, one more thing - in my rant about it being bad, I'm talking about full-size images. If you have smaller bitmaps, it's certainly okay to pass them as a Parcelable.

Comment: I may end up doing that though since I want to replicate the contact image picker, select an image and crop it. but I'll post that in another question, thanks!

Comment: Please [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644614/failed-to-pass-image-to-another-class/33644701#33644701) me..thanks

Comment: greatest answer

Comment: Does this solution require android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: The official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles says "We recommend that you keep saved state to less than 50k of data".

Answer (score 45):

If you pass it as a Parcelable, you're bound to get a JAVA BINDER FAILURE error.  So, the solution is this:  If the bitmap is small, like, say, a thumbnail, pass it as a byte array and build the bitmap for display in the next activity.  For instance:

in your calling activity...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
Bitmap b; // your bitmap
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
startActivity(i);
```

...and in your receiving activity

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
    ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);        
    previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this helps avoid a Java Binder Failure?

Comment: And if the bitmap is not very small?

Comment: Why are you compressing the file, when you don't use the compressed version anyhow?

Comment: @user1767754 It's being compressed into the `bs` variable which is used.

Comment: It does not works for [me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644614/failed-to-pass-image-to-another-class/33644701#336447010)

Comment: you should not pass a bitmap through binder without knowing how big it is. You are most likely getting a Binder Failure

Comment: Does anybody know how big must be the bitmap to get `out of memory` error?

Comment: I would use Parcelable when bitmap is small. The problem comes when you are passing more than 1mb of data in bundle.

Comment: it works but for large size image do not work, it says system do not allow...

Answer (score 24):

As suggested by @EboMike I saved the bitmap in a file named **myImage** in the internal storage of my application not accessible my other apps. Here's the code of that part:

```
public String createImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fileName = "myImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close file output
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fileName = null;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Then in the next activity you can decode this file **myImage** to a bitmap using following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context
                    .openFileInput("myImage"));//here context can be anything like getActivity() for fragment, this or MainActivity.this
```

**Note** A lot of checking for null and scaling bitmap's is ommited.

Comment: do I have to delete the file after?

Comment: @alfo888_ibg I dont think you need to delete the image because every time you use the function the previous image is overwritten. However you could delete it if you wanted to

Comment: Probably should delete it.

Comment: Does this require android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at all?

Comment: @AlanNelson You dont need the permission if you save the image in the apps private storage. If you save it in public folder like gallery you would need the permission.

Answer (score 9):

**Activity**

***To pass a bitmap between Activites***

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);
```

***And in the Activity class***

```
Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
```

---

**Fragment**

***To pass a bitmap between Fragments***

```
SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

***To receive inside the SecondFragment***

```
Bitmap bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("bitmap");
```

---

**Transferring large bitmap (Compress bitmap)**

If you are getting failed binder transaction, this means you are exceeding the binder transaction buffer by transferring large element from one activity to another activity.

**So in that case you have to compress the bitmap as an byte's array and then uncompress it in another activity**, like this

***In the FirstActivity***

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, stream);
byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); 
intent.putExtra("bitmapbytes",bytes);
```

***And in the SecondActivity***

```
byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bitmapbytes");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: where in firstactivity should the above code be used. Should it be in init or as a seperate method ( and call this method in secondactivity ??

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap is [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) so you can add using [putExtra(String,Parcelable)][2] method, But not sure it is a best practice, If it is large size data it is better to store in a single place and use from both activities.

[2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Parcelable)

Answer (score 2):

in first.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, second.class);
                    i.putExtra("uri",uri);
                    startActivity(i);
```

in second.java

```
Bundle bd = getIntent().getExtras();
        Uri uri = bd.getParcelable("uri");
        Log.e("URI", uri.toString());
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: is imageShow an object of imageView?

Answer (score 1):

I had to rescale the bitmap a bit to not exceed the 1mb limit of the transaction binder. You can adapt the 400 the your screen or make it dinamic it's just meant to be an example.
It works fine and the quality is nice.
Its also a lot faster then saving the image and loading it after but you have the size limitation.

```
public void loadNextActivity(){
    Intent confirmBMP = new Intent(this,ConfirmBMPActivity.class);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bmp = returnScaledBMP();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

    confirmBMP.putExtra("Bitmap",bmp);
    startActivity(confirmBMP);
    finish();

}
public Bitmap returnScaledBMP(){
    Bitmap bmp=null;
    bmp = tempBitmap;
    bmp = createScaledBitmapKeepingAspectRatio(bmp,400);
    return bmp;
```

}

After you recover the bmp in your nextActivity with the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmBMP);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");

}
```

I hope my answer was somehow helpfull.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Write this code from where you want to Intent into next activity.

```
    yourimageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
    Drawable drawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable(); 
    Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Image", imageBitmap);
```

In onCreate Function of NextActivity.class

```
Bitmap hotel_image;
Intent intent = getIntent();
hotel_image= intent.getParcelableExtra("Image");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass image in short without using bundle like this
This is the code of sender .class file

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher;
Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent.setClass(<Sender_Activity>.this, <Receiver_Activity.class);
Intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);
startActivity(intent);
```

and this is receiver class file code.

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
ImageView viewBitmap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bitmapview);
viewBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

No need to compress.
that's it

Answer (score 0):

It's better to save the file in temp/cache folder and pass the file path through intent data as I did it. here is sample code:

from on Button Click (Here bitmapFullScreen is a bitmap data which I have collected from Live Server)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullscreenActivity.class);
String fPath = CreateTempFile(bitmapFullScreen);
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(fPath)) {
    intent.putExtra("image", fPath);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Function to create a File on Temp/Cache folder

```
public String CreateTempFile(Bitmap mBitmap) {
    File f3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/inpaint/");
    if (!f3.exists())
        f3.mkdirs();

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyhhmmss", Locale.US);
    String FN = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/inpaint/" + dateFormatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".png";
    File file = new File(FN);
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

2nd File where we need the file

Global var

```
String FileName = "";
```

Receive the Intent String data as FilePath to View Image on ImageView
this code will be onCreate

```
ImageView imgUpload = findViewById(R.id.imgUpload);
try {
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("image")) {
        FileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FileName);
        imgUpload.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

After display the Image we need to delete temp file

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    try {
        File file = new File(FileName);
        file.delete();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```