# How to send image from one activity to another activity that is selected from the android Gallery?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I want to set the Image to be Selected from the Android Gallery.
I use this code to get selected Image.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("image/*"); 
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);// 
//startActivity(intent);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);
```

And the onActivityResult Method is like:

```
    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     
        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {             
            Uri contentUri = data.getData();          
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };         
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);         
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);         
            cursor.moveToFirst();         
            String tmppath = cursor.getString(column_index);           
            Bitmap croppedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmppath);
            go.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 130, 100, null);
            //previewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            imageSrc.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);    //set to your imageview          
        }
}
```

Now, I want to select Image from the gallery and send it to another activity. So how it is Possible with above code ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `URI` of the Image to next `Activity`.

the `URI` which you get from `onActivityResult()`

and in `onCreate()` of the next `Activity`.

Decode the `Bitmap` again and set it to `ImageView`

Answer (score 1):

passing the Image from one activity to another was too much expensive rather than you can pass it's image path as string and load.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4352172/760489) post

Answer (score 0):

in OnActivityResult

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("bmp",croppedImage);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity

```
Bitmap bmp = this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bmp");
```