# Passing Custom object with bitmap to another activity?

Tags: android

MyObject class

```
public class MemberDetailsObject implements Serializable {

String memberid;
String memberName;
String mobileNumber;
String photo;
String phoneType;
String latitute ;
String longitude;
String dateNTime;
String locationName;
String date;
String time;
Bitmap memberImage;
public String getMemberid() {
    return memberid;
}
public void setMemberid(String memberid) {
    this.memberid = memberid;
}
public String getMemberName() {
    return memberName;
}
public void setMemberName(String memberName) {
    this.memberName = memberName;
}
public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}
public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}
public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
public String getPhoneType() {
    return phoneType;
}
public void setPhoneType(String phoneType) {
    this.phoneType = phoneType;
}
public String getLatitute() {
    return latitute;
}
public void setLatitute(String latitute) {
    this.latitute = latitute;
}
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
public String getDateNTime() {
    return dateNTime;
}
public void setDateNTime(String dateNTime) {
    this.dateNTime = dateNTime;
}
public String getLocationName() {
    return locationName;
}
public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
    this.locationName = locationName;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
public Bitmap getMemberImage() {
    return memberImage;
}
public void setMemberImage(Bitmap memberImage) {
    this.memberImage = memberImage;
}
public MemberDetailsObject(String memberid, String memberName,
        String mobileNumber, String photo, String phoneType, String latitute,
        String longitude, String dateNTime, String locationName, String date,
        String time, Bitmap memberImage) {
    super();
    this.memberid = memberid;
    this.memberName = memberName;
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.phoneType = phoneType;
    this.latitute = latitute;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.dateNTime = dateNTime;
    this.locationName = locationName;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.memberImage = memberImage;
}




}
```

I am trying to pass it using

```
Intent viewProfile = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenMemberProfile.class);       
viewProfile.putExtra("memberList", memberList.get(positon));
```

however the problem is that bitmap is not serilizable, may i know any other alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `Bitmap` through `Activities` is possible but is very expensive for memory.
Instead of passing a `Bitmap` object you should save it on external memory (cache / sd card) and pass its path (wrapped in `Serializable` Object) to the next `Activity`, and in the next Activity decode that path into `Bitmap` and use accordingly.

```
public class MemberDetailsObject implements Serializable {
    // other member ... 
    String memberImagePath;
    // rest of the class ...
}
```

For more detail see here:

[How to send image from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008915/how-to-send-image-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-that-is-selected-from-th/8008992#8008992)

[how do you pass images (bitmaps) between android activities using bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4352172/593709)

Answer (score 0):

A Bitmap ist Parcelable so you can put it in an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way send bitmap to other activity as the bitmap is not serilizable , but implement

> Parcelable

[How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-1-activity-to-another)