# Android Passing Bitmap Through Activity

Tags: android

i currently have a class that uses bitmap. however it is not serializable due to bitmap. Right now i am wondering which are the best ways to deal with it.

Should i be storing it on the cache or sdcard? How ong does bitmap saved in cache or sdcard stays? is there any tutorial for doing those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass bitmap object from one activity to another.Take a look at the following:

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable`, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: however i am using a custom object with bitmap inside which is not serlizable

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076102/passing-custom-object-with-bitmap-to-another-activity