# How to pass bitmap from one activity to another

Tags: android, bitmap

i have bitmap in ActivityA i want to pass the bitmap from here to ActivityB, i googled for this. when i use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

for getting

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

i am getting this error **!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!** .
how can i solve this problem.

Comment: what do you mean with "sometime works, but not all the times"? which effects do you see on screen (or in logcat if you get errors)?

Comment: check my answer edited answer you can also use Application class.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577664/pass-a-bitmap-image-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 13):

Your code is correct for putting bitmaps into the extras and works fine for me with small images.
But it seems that there is a limit for the size of the Parcelable extra. See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7322a84adcfee567?pli=1.

You might want to store the image first and only hand over the URI to the store location.

Edit: Using a public static field for the bitmap as suggested by udaykiran  violates so many OO principles I don't even know where to start.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THAT EDIT. I've downvoted the two answers that suggested it and left harsh comments, which I never do, because it's simply **terribad**. I wish I could upvote this a few more times.

Answer (score 3):

I tried and its working as below using `intent.putExtra("name", bitmap)`

While passing with intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Current.this, Next.class);
intent.putExtra("bmp", bitmap);
startActivity(intent);
```

While fetching,

```
Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bmp");
```

**OR**

Other option is to use Application class,

You can also use a class that extends `Application` and have a setter getter for Bitmap and call it from every Acitivity.

```
((myApplication_class_name)getApplication()).setBitmap(bmp);
```

and fetch the Bitmap using,

```
((myApplication_class_name)getApplication()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: i created like as u said but not getting in ActivityB

Comment: i decleared in ActivityA private static Bitmap b; try to get in this class Bitmap a = ImageAfterCrop.b;

Comment: you have to declare as public static not private static.

Comment: can i decler this in my ActivityB  public static Bitmap b

Comment: Sorry but storing Bitmaps in memory statically is just poor coding. There is a good chance you may be causing memory leaks. Store the image in some temp cache and pass the URI instead.

Comment: This is **awful** design, not a solution but a workaround, and the OP obviously did not have the knowledge to tell. I rarely downvote, but come on...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is the right method... you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4352194/696145) for the feature to be implemented. i too have used something like this itself.

Answer (score -5):

You can simply name you `Bitmap` as `static` first.

then create a method like

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(){
return bitmap;
}
```

then you can simply call from other activities,

```
bitmapwantedclass.getBitmap();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i  done as u said but getting error in the wanted class  The method getBitmapCrop() is undefined for the type ImageAfterCrop

Comment: You have to call like this, suppose your bitmap is in class A and getBitmap is in A , you want that bitmap in class B, so you have to call A.getBitmap() in class B.

Comment: This is **awful** design, not a solution but a workaround, and the OP obviously did not have the knowledge to tell. I rarely downvote, but come on...

Comment: Why is he getting down voted? Sure it's not good design. But the standard way to write to disk then extract is extremely slow for high resolution photos even testing on new phones like the Nexus II.