# Changing the imageView object in android after loading the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am making an application in Android, which requires sending bitmap object from one activity and displaying that bitmap object sent on the second activity page. But , I am getting a blank screen

Here is a sample of my code for sending the Bitmap object :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Display2.this, Display3.class);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now the part of code on second activity to retrieve the sent object and displaying it on screen :-

```
public class Display3 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        ImageView myIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        bitmap = bitmap.createBitmap(myIV.getWidth(), myIV.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        myIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        setContentView(R.layout.display3);

    }
}
```

can anyone suggest whats wrong in this part ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmap implements Parcelable object, so you could always pass it in the intent like below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: But making the suggested changes displays an error in the code

Comment: check weather the bitmap is made successfully to bitmap-object or not

Answer (score 2):

this is not good for passing bitmap from one activity to another..

You can simply name you Bitmap as static first.
then create a method like

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return bitmap;
}
```

then you can simply call from other activities,

```
bitmapexistingclass.getBitmap();
```

if we use intents for passing bitmap we will get some errors check this question [How to pass bitmap from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8255123/964741)

Answer (score 1):

from your code above you are creating an empty bitmap:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

I do not see any reason why from this code you'll get anything else then blank black bitmap with hight and width equals to the imageView hight and width

Comment: After doing the changes, it says unable to start activity :(

Comment: well, that's another story :)  but if you'll write the code that you changed, and atach the stack trace log - maybe I could help with that

Answer (score 0):

what you are expecting from android to fill drawing in `Bitmap` itself , you are creating an Empty `Bitmap` `Object` with height and width equavalent to `ImageView` object;
as Bitmap implements `Parcelable` you can simply put it in bundle and retrive on other `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Use below two methods to convert a bitmap to string and vice versa. Then you can pass the string with intents from activity to another activity. I too do the same in my application.
Then we dont need to use ParcelableExtra and serialzable class.

```
public String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap src) {
if(src!= null){
ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
src.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,(OutputStream) os);
byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);  
}
return null;            
}

public Bitmap getBitMapFromString(String src){
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if(src!= null){
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(src.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.length);
return bitmap;
}
return null;
}
```