# How i pass Bitmap or Drawable from one Activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I would like to pass Bitmap or Drawable from one Activity to another, now i'm doing this:

```
            EventPhoto photo = (EventPhoto) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            BitmapDrawable test = (BitmapDrawable) photo.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = test.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos); 
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

            Intent intent = new Intent(EventDetailActivity.this, ImageExpandActivity.class);
            System.out.println(b.length); //B LENGTH = 908k
            intent.putExtra("image",b);
            startActivity(intent);
```

My problem is when i try to use putExtra, he don't send any exception, nothing, but don't respond and Android kill application, why this is happen?
I'm thinking its about size because everything works when i pass a little image.

I'm looking for and find few solutions like this: [How to pass bitmap from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255123/how-to-pass-bitmap-from-one-activity-to-another)
but i want to use putExtra, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: One possibility is to save it to the SD card or whatever, then pass the file's path with the Intent.  But I'm also hoping someone has an idea on how to avoid that.

Comment: Post the stack trace from LogCat for your force close.

Comment: Also read this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't find any different solution so I solved with this:
[How to pass bitmap from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255123/how-to-pass-bitmap-from-one-activity-to-another)

same link I gave before with static attribute:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(){
   return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't go to disc (files, db, etc) if you just need this data temporarily. I'd go for your same approach.

You have several options for that. Just take whatever fits better to your app.

- public static class, available all along your code. This kind of helpers are handy for managing things like shared preferences or some global information you might need to have there
- [Singleton](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/SingletonPattern.shtml), this pattern is very similar to the previous one. Main difference is that in this case you have just one instance of the class (in static there's no instance, just access to vars and methods). This pattern is helpful whenever you need any reference instance for the whole lifecycle of your app.
- Extend application. This goes a step further from the other two. You have an instance of  your Application available in the whole lifecycle. Normally you may want to manage some other stuff there, like push, or error notifications, services, etc. [Example](https://github.com/JlUgia/ants_approach/blob/master/src/ugia/ants/application/AntsApplication.java)