# Passing bitmap to other activity getting message on logcat FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmapimage

when i'm passing bitmap image to other activity i'm getting mag on logcat as-

```
 03-20 12:06:56.553: E/JavaBinder(280): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

it's happening for large size image.small size image is working well.
what should i do?please help me.thanks in advance.

here i'm passing data as-

```
Drawable drbl=_imageView.getDrawable();
    int imageh=_imageView.getHeight();
    int imagew=_imageView.getWidth();
    Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)drbl).getBitmap();
    intent.putExtra("Image_Height", imageh);
    intent.putExtra("Image_Width", imagew);
    intent.putExtra("Bitmap",bit);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Comment: Please dont put bitmap in extra..... carrying that much of data is not a good approach. Save some sort of static refrence of bitmap and after using it recycle it.

Comment: Or save bitmap as a file and then re-use this, that would be the best approach ATM.

Comment: is your bitmap stored in sdcard. you can pass the the path of the bitmap and retrieve it in the second activity using the path.

Comment: exactly what should i have to do? because i'm making some changes in the bitmap(like canvas drawing),so that bitmap only i have pass in next activity,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255123/how-to-pass-bitmap-from-one-activity-to-another. This has been discussed numerous times on SO

Answer (score 2):

Putting that amount of data in **extras** is not a good approach. Easiest work around is keep a static reference of the new Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(Bitmap changeBitmap){
return bitmap;
}
```

And after using it recyle it i this manner.

```
if(changedBitmap!=origanlBitmap)
orignalBitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: i tried this.but still its working for small image not for large image.

Comment: Simply try static Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)drbl).getBitmap(); and in your other activity get that bit map by Bitmap newBit=previousactivity.bit;

Comment: i have voted for the commentSimply try static Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)drbl).getBitmap(); and in your other activity get that bit map by Bitmap newBit=previousactivity.bit; because its working not the above getbitmap method

Comment: Sorry missed that part. Thanks