# Setting image as bitmap in multiple imageViews

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, bitmapimage

I have two imageViews and when the user clicks on a button, it sends them to the gallery to choose an image. The image they choose then shows up in the imageView where they can then either do one of two things depending on what they are setting:
1) The background
2) The icon

I had the background working fine but now I am trying to include the option to set the icon. I have the imageView for the icon here (in widget.xml):

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bwidgetOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>
```

Here is my two classes for the coding:
Personalize.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;
IMPORTS
public class Personalize extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button;
ImageView image;
ImageView image2;
Button btnChangeImage;
Button btnChangeImageForIcon;
Button btnSetBackground;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_2 = 2;
private String  selectedImagePath;
Bitmap background;
Bitmap b2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.personalize);
Log.d("Personalize", "OnCreate called");

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);

Button btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);    
btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(this);

Button btnChangeImageForIcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon); 
btnChangeImageForIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

Button btnSetBackground = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetBackground);
btnSetBackground.setOnClickListener(this);

Button btnLinkToFeedback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToFeedback);

Button btnSetIcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetIcon);
btnSetIcon.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
switch (v.getId()) { 
case R.id.btnChangeImage: 
launchImageChooser(); 
break; 
case R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon: 
launchImageChooser(); 
break; 
case R.id.btnSetBackground: 
setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop(); 
break; 
case R.id.btnSetIcon:
setIconImageInWidget();
break;
} 
} 

private void setIconImageInWidget() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("Personalize", "setIconImageInWidget() called");
Intent i = getIntent();
//Convert bitmap to byte array to send back to activity
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android
scaleDownBitmapForIcon(b2, 500, this.getBaseContext());
Log.d("Personalize", "Scale Bitmap Chosen For Icon");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[]byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

i.putExtra("myIconBitmap", byteArray);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
}


public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap background, int newHeight, Context c) {

final float densityMultiplier = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

int h= (int) (500*densityMultiplier);
int w= (int) (h * background.getWidth()/((double) background.getHeight()));

background=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, w, h, true);
// TO SOLVE LOOK AT HERE:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517176/passing-bitmap-to-other-activity-getting-message-on-logcat-failed-binder-transac
return background;
}

public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmapForIcon(Bitmap b2, int newHeight, Context c) {

final float densityMultiplier = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

int h= (int) (500*densityMultiplier);
int w= (int) (h * b2.getWidth()/((double) b2.getHeight()));

b2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2, w, h, true);
// TO SOLVE LOOK AT HERE:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517176/passing-bitmap-to-other-activity-getting-message-on-logcat-failed-binder-transac
return b2;
}

private void setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop() {
Log.d("Personalize", "setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop() called");
Intent i = getIntent();
//Convert bitmap to byte array to send back to activity
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android
scaleDownBitmap(background, 500, this.getBaseContext());
Log.d("Personalize", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
background.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[]byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

i.putExtra("myBackgroundBitmap", byteArray);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
}

private void launchImageChooser() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_2);
Log.d("Personalize", "launchImageChooser called");
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
if(cursor != null) {
cursor.close();
}
return imagePath;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    background = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(background != null){
        image.setImageBitmap(background); 
    }           
} else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_2)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap b2 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(b2 != null){
        image2.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }
}    
}
}

private Bitmap getAndDecodeImage(String  selectedImagePath){
try {
    Log.d("Personalize", "selectedImagePath: " + selectedImagePath);
    FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
    bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

    if (fileis != null) 
    {
        fileis.close();
    }
    if (bufferedstream != null) 
    {
        bufferedstream.close();
    }
    return bMap;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {                   
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
return null;
}


public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
   }
}

}
```

Then Drag_and_Drop.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Drag_and_Drop_App extends Activity {
private static final int SET_BACKGROUND = 10;
private static final int SET_ICON = 20;

private ListView mListAppInfo;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;
public AppInfoAdapter adapter;
final SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set layout for the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    Log.d("D&D", "onCreate called");
}
public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) { 
     Bitmap thumbnail = null; 
     try { 
     File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename); 
     FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath); 
     thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi); 
     } catch (Exception ex) { 
     Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage()); 
     } 
     return thumbnail; 
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
     Log.i("Drag_and_Drop_App", "requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode); 
     if(requestCode == SET_BACKGROUND && resultCode == RESULT_OK){ 
     byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("myBackgroundBitmap"); 
     Bitmap myBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); 
     setBackgroundImage(myBackground); 
     } 
     else if(requestCode == SET_ICON && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("myIconBitmap"); 
         Bitmap myIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); 
         setBackgroundImageForIcon(myIcon); 
     }
     } 


     @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
     private void setBackgroundImage(Bitmap bitmap) { 
     RelativeLayout yourBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_drag_and_drop_app); 

     Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); 

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { 
     yourBackgroundView.setBackgroundDrawable(d); 
     } else { 
     yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d); 
     } 
     } 

     @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
     private void setBackgroundImageForIcon(Bitmap bitmap) { 
     LinearLayout yourIconView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.widgetXMl); 

     Drawable dq = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); 

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { 
     yourIconView.setBackgroundDrawable(dq); 
     } else { 
     yourIconView.setBackground(dq); 
     } 
     } 

     }
```

The issue that I have right now is that when I click the button to choose a icon image, I go to the gallery and choose a picture but then it reloads the gallery and makes me choose another image (which ends up going to the other image view as well). How can I fix this?

Here is my Personalize.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customize" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeBackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customizebackground"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:maxWidth="100dp"  
    android:maxHeight="100dp"  
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
    android:contentDescription="@string/descForBackground"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_background" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/set_background" 
    android:id="@+id/btnSetBackground" />

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_icon"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:maxWidth="100dp"  
    android:maxHeight="100dp"  
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descForIcon"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImageForIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_icon" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/set_icon" 
    android:id="@+id/btnSetIcon" />

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToFeedback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/Send_Feedback"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, is there a way that I can clean up my code so that I am not repeating as much?

I understand that this is A BUNCH of code to look through but I would really apperciate it if someone could.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`it reloads the gallery and makes me choose another image`

Because you are calling `startActivityForResult` two times

```
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_2);
```

in launchImageChooser(). change this code.