# Check when onClick is checked only?

Tags: android

I have a checkbox, that when checked, makes a bitmap and then saves that bitmap to internal storage. Then, in a gridView adapter, I have it check for the bitmap from internal storage with FileInputstream.

The issue is that the checkbox's onClick method is also in a class that extends baseadapter.

With the way it is now, when I start my app, it automatically checks for the bitmap and then returns a FileNotFound exception and then the onClick of the checkbox doesn't do anything.

I thought about this and realized that the reason it checks for it is that it is creating the gridView when I first open my app (which it is supposed to). In other words, it checks for the file because it is in the getView() method of my gridView adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bitmapA = null;
        FileInputStream in = Context.openFileInput("bitmapA");
        bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
        /*BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA = new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        */view.setImageBitmap(bitmapA);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        /*if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}
```

Is there a way that I can make it check internal storage ONLY IF the checkbox is checked?
Please note that the onClick method of the checkbox is in one class while I am getting the bitmap in another.

Here are my two full classes:

AppInfoAdapter (the one with the onClick method---I will only post the needed coding here):

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<ResolveInfo> mListAppInfo;
private PackageManager mPackManager;
private List<ResolveInfo> originalListAppInfo;
private Filter filter;
private String fname;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<ResolveInfo> listApp,
        PackageManager pm) {
    mContext = c;
    this.originalListAppInfo = this.mListAppInfo = listApp;
    mPackManager = pm;
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "top");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "getCount()");
    return mListAppInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "getItem");
    return mListAppInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "getItemId");
    return position;
}

public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap default_b, int newHeight, Context c) {

    final float densityMultiplier = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    int h= (int) (100*densityMultiplier);
    int w= (int) (h * default_b.getWidth()/((double) default_b.getHeight()));

    default_b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(default_b, w, h, true);
    // TO SOLVE LOOK AT HERE:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517176/passing-bitmap-to-other-activity-getting-message-on-logcat-failed-binder-transac
    return default_b;
}

public void SaveImage(Bitmap default_b) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n +".png";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "" + file);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            //  + "/" + fname + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = mContext.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("bitmapA", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        // FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the selected entry
    final ResolveInfo entry = (ResolveInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
        Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "New layout inflated");
    }

    // load controls from layout resources
    ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tvAppName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPkgName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);
    final CheckBox addCheckbox = (CheckBox) v
            .findViewById(R.id.addCheckbox);
    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Controls from layout Resources Loaded");

    // set data to display
    ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
    tvAppName.setText(entry.activityInfo.loadLabel(mPackManager));
    tvPkgName.setText(entry.activityInfo.packageName);

    Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Data Set To Display");
    addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                            .getApplicationIcon(entry.activityInfo.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon
                                scaleDownBitmap(default_b, 100, v.getContext());
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");

                                SaveImage(default_b);
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scaled BM saved to External Storage");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridViewAdapter.class);
                                // intent.hasExtra("bitmapA");
                                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Intent started to send Bitmap");

                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
            });

    // return view
    return v;
}
```

GridViewAdapter:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context Context;

// Keep all Images in array list
public ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Constructor
public GridViewAdapter(Context c){
    Context = c;
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "Constructor is set");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "pattern1 added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "pattern2 added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.trashcan);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "trashcan added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "ic_launcher added");

    Bitmap default_b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picture");  
}

@Override
// How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
public int getCount() {
    return drawables.size();
}

@Override
// Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
// data set
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drawables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bitmapA = null;
        FileInputStream in = Context.openFileInput("bitmapA");
        bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
        /*BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA = new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        */view.setImageBitmap(bitmapA);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        /*if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}

}
```

FURTHER UPDATED CODING:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    boolean checked = (mCheckBox==null)?false:(((CheckBox)  mCheckBox).isChecked());
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    if(checked = true){
    try {
        Bitmap bitmapA = null;
        FileInputStream in = Context.openFileInput("bitmapA");
        bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
        /*BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA = new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        */view.setImageBitmap(bitmapA);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        /*if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

PLUS I ADDED THIS METHOD:

```
public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkbox){
    mCheckBox=checkbox;
}
```

AND THIS VARIABLE:

```
CheckBox mCheckBox=null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to listen to the onClick event in the adapter. 
Instead, you can read the checkbox status.

for this, in your adapter, you add a field and a setter:

```
CheckBox mCheckBox=null;

public void setCheckBox( CheckBox  checkbox){

         mCheckBox=checkbox;
}
```

and then, in the getView(), you add thiss line at the begining;

```
boolean checked = (mCheckBox==null)?false:(((CheckBox)  mCheckBox).isChecked());
```

**UPDATE**

then in your activity, i suppose you have something like

```
GridViewAdapter mGridViewAdapter= new GridViewAdapter(this);
```

so, below you have to add:

```
CheckBox mCheckBox = findViewById(R,id.YOURCHECKBOXID);
mGridViewAdapter.setCheckBox(mCheckBox);
```

And that's it!

Comment: Ok so I add the field and setter to my adapter for the gridView? and then also how can I use that checked boolean? Would I get my checkbox via findViewById and then somehow use that in an if statement? I added my two classes above in the question if you want to take a look at what I currently have. Thanks.

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you did now. Thanks! Can you check the question under the "FURTHER UPDATED CODING" section and make sure I understood right? and just to make sure, would I replace the "checkbox" in the setCheckBox method with my checkbox? Or how would I go about making sure that when the checkbox is checked and it's status is read, it's reading from that checkbox?

Comment: Thanks! That ended up not fixing the problem *I apparently guessed wrong* but it did do something I know that! Plus you did answer the question and it makes sense. I'll just have to ask more questions from here :)