# How to send Listview item data (image & text) from one activity to another activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I am working on application in which user will be able to retrieve data from weburl using json and i have made that module, but now i want to show selected listview item in another activity using intent in which i have to show them Image and Text of selected Item...could you please show me some source code or way to write the code for the same one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inflating a view from JSON data, couldn't you just send the JSON string as an extra with the activity intent, and the inflate the view inside the second activity?
For example,

```
Intent.putExtra("json",mJson);
```

where mJson is the name of your string object containing the JSON. Then in your other activity's onResume, do something like

```
mJson = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json");
```

And then inflate the view using that JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You can not simply add image into your bundle.you can add your text simply like
Intent.putExtra("text",yourText);

To add image into bundle refer this,

[how do you pass images (bitmaps) between android activities using bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles)

You have to use parceble object within bundle.