# Can't pass image to second activity

Tags: android, image, android-intent

Since yesterday I've tried every solution here in SO for "How to pass image in second activity" and related. None of them helped me so I would need some help. I don't have problem to pass another strings etc. but image didn't want to go into activity2.
 Here is my code and what I take and tried [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908048/passing-bitmap-between-two-activities)

FirstActivity

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(Restaurants.this, RestaurantInformation.class);

      intent.putExtra("id", restaurantAdaptor.getItemId(position));
      intent.putExtra("text", stocks[position].text); 
      intent.putExtra("name", stocks[position].name);

      ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
      byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();

      intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
  }

 });
```

In the received activity I have this

```
String text, name;
ImageView imgView;

long rest_id;
TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_informations);

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {

        rest_id = b.getLong("id");
        txtView.setText(rest_id+"");

        name = b.getString("name");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name+"");

        text = b.getString("text");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text+"");


        Bitmap bmp;

        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

When I click on listview item the app crash and in the `LogCat` I get this

```
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): Process: com.reserveme, PID: 1799
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.reserveme.Restaurants$1.onItemClick(Restaurants.java:101)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-18 04:16:25.746: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line number `101` in `Restaurants` is

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
```

Comment: Your log report says you have another problem not about the problem you are asking. there is a NullPointerException in  Restaurants.java:101. please check that line why it gets null.

Comment: I don't know why it gets null since I get the image on first activity and everything is shown correctly there.

Comment: can you tell me in which line you are getting null?

Comment: It is in the question under the LogCat -> `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);`

Comment: did you declared bitmap and bStream correctly? if you're getting the error on that line, all code posted before is irrelevant since it looks alright. i guess

Comment: I have for bitmap `public Bitmap bitmap;`

Comment: In that case i think "bitmap" is null. please check when performing click it gets null or not. You just declared it " public Bitmap bitmap;" please initialize that bitmap

Comment: According to `LogCat` is null but the image is there?

Comment: you need to initialize your bitmap by your image. I think you haven't done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use
Activity 1:

```
try {
    //Write file
    String filename = "bitmap.png";
    FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

    //Cleanup
    stream.close();
    bmp.recycle();

    //Pop intent
    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    in1.putExtra("image", filename);
    startActivity(in1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Activity 2, load up the bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
try {
    FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Solution to your Problem

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(Restaurants.this, RestaurantInformation.class);

      intent.putExtra("id", restaurantAdaptor.getItemId(position));
      intent.putExtra("text", stocks[position].text); 
      intent.putExtra("name", stocks[position].name);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        final Bitmap yourBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();



      ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
      byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();

      intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
  }

 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your method and the app doesn't crash but again there is no image. And in logcat is same line error + on this line in second activity `FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);` and when I check with `Log.e` what is returned for image I see this `android.widget.ImageView{b2ebe100 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f080023 app:id/image1}`

Comment: You do not pass an imageView, but the image

Comment: Well.. is what I'm trying. I have no idea why is trying to pass the ImageView.

Comment: get image bitmap from imageView, like this Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: Where should I put this? In `try` block or outside? In `setOnItemClickListener`?

Comment: where is your ImageView  ?

Comment: It is in `onCreate` where are all other TextView's and ListView `image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);`

Comment: if you paste your complete code, i will able to help you

Comment: I've posted full source for activity1 in pastebin. Please check it here - http://pastebin.com/NGAX9AbS

Comment: so you want restaurant image from the listview row which is clicked to be send to another activity ?

Comment: Yes. This listview currently contain text, name and image. They are passed successfully  to second activity but image doesn't.

Comment: Now I get this in `Logcat` `11-18 05:17:11.606: W/Bundle(2051): Key image expected String but value was a [B.  The default value <null> was returned.
11-18 05:17:11.616: W/Bundle(2051): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
11-18 05:17:11.616: W/Bundle(2051): java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String
`

Comment: and this is still there also `android.widget.ImageView{b2ebe100 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f080023 app:id/image1}`

Comment: I've put my old source in activity2 - `byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);` and the image is there. But whit your is not.

Comment: thats good. it means your problem is solved, probably I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I still see this in log `android.widget.ImageView{b2ebe100 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f080023 app:id/image1}` but at least the image is there. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should save the image to some location in phone and then pass the URI of that saved image through intent. And access that URI in second activity.

use this code to save file

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(path, "filename.jpg"); // the File to save to
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

Bitmap pictureBitmap = getImageBitmap(myurl); // obtaining the Bitmap
pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
fOut.flush();
fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: I loaded this images from MySQL. So you suggest to store them in phone and then to use the path?

Comment: yup..This way your activity transition will be fast and you will neglect the risk of OutOfMemoryError

Comment: I still don't know how exactly to make this.

Comment: if your image is too large you will have TransactionTooLargeException, so you can google how to save bitmap to file and then use that file URi

Comment: No, they are small images. I'm confused what to put in `myurl`?

Comment: pictureBitmap is you bitmap from sql,dirrectly compress it and use it to save