# How to transfer bitmap image from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image

I have an a bitmap image in my Activity like this:

```
Bitmap image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hello);
        image1.setImageBitmap(image4);
```

I'm trying to pass this image in fragment using this code:

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                Secondfrag yourFragment = new Secondfrag();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("BitmapImage",image4);

                yourFragment.setArguments(b);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag, yourFragment, "FRAGMENT");
               fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and trying to get this image in fragment like this:

```
Bundle b=this.getArguments();
        String page=b.getString("BitmapImage");

        image2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(page));
```

But there is no image display in my Fragment.How to resolve this issue?

Comment: passing a reference would be good idea i think

Comment: As @TahmidRahman said, you can pass the reference :)

Comment: You can do it by saving in internal storage..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it into byte array

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putByteArray("image",byteArray);


  // your fragment code 
fragment.setArguments(b);
```

Get value from destination fragment

```
byte[] byteArray = getArgument().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797090/4316327

Answer (score 0):

Passing image reference is a good way rather than passing whole image data.

In your case you could pass your image `Uri`

If you want to get image from internal storage the you can pass `Uri`. But if you just want a specific resource (i.e. `drawable`) then, it could just pass its name (which is `String`).

You can check this solution [Passing Uri to an Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017425/6155248)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass your image path/URI in the bundle.

In your case you are using your resources to make the Bitmap. You can use the same code to get the bitmap in your fragment. Resources are available in the fragment as getActivity().getResources();

```
Bitmap image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.hello);
    image1.setImageBitmap(image4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method

```
private void nextpageintent(String photoUri){

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("photo", photoUri);
picture picture = new picture();
picture .setArguments(bundle); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, picture); 
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here, this issue you can simply solve using getter setter of the Singleton class,
First make one Ben class for your bitmap storage.

```
class BitmapStorage {
private static volatile BitmapStorage instance = null;
private Bitmap bitmap = null;
private BitmapStorage () {}

    public static BitmapStorage getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(BitmapStorage.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new BitmapStorage();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
           return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
           this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then after in your activity set bitmap into your model class. Like

```
BitmapStrorage bs = getInstance ();
Bitmap image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hello);
Bs.setBitmap(image4);
```

whenever fragment call according to fragment life cycle then OnCreate method first call, so here we can check bitmap is null or not and get bitmap and use it. may not check this solution but i thing it's work for you.