# Multiple Activities, showing images in another activity

Tags: android, image, android-activity

I am creating one app with two activities, an image will load and shows in another activity,

this is my LogCat error, 
http://pastebin.com/BvLtcdz0

This is MainActivity.java code
http://pastebin.com/9F1sNr8B

Comment: This is ImageDisplayActivity.java code
http://pastebin.com/ntvf5Tt6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAssets()` needs a `context` which you don't have until you call `onCreate()` move

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
```

into `onCreate()`

Images can be sent through `Intents` but it is better to save a file path and send the path then open from file with a `String` path sent through the `Intent`

Comment: Okay Uncle I will try it :)

Comment: Ok, but I have to ask...why do you keep calling me uncle?

Comment: Hi uncle, can go to other activity but it is not loading :) Aww because you are older than me uncle that is why I keep calling you uncle, not only to you, people who are older than me are aunties and uncles :)

Comment: Ok, just had to ask because I was curious. Read my edit. There are posts from Google developers as to why this is best and I can try and post a link when I have time but you should try and do it that way. Otherwise, post on here or new post what the error you get now. Or check the link that @HalIR posted...it seems to have the answer to your problem now after fixing your original problem

Comment: Ok Uncle I will do it, I am searching and coding the whole day and haven't slept yet, btw thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome. Also, I know its hard to quit thinking about your problem (I still dream about programming) but no matter what deadlines are, usually it is good to walk away for awhile. You will be amazed at the problems you can solve when you take a little break.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly, you need to convert it to a bitmap first

```
yourImageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap passedBitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourOtherActivity.class;
Intent.putExtra("passedBitmap", passedBitmap);

startActivity(intent);
```

then load it back up in your other activity

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("passedBitmap");
```

Found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13226283/793607) (maybe dupe)

Comment: By the way, still can't solve it, I change to this way but it is not working yet :(

Comment: Are you able to set a break point and check values?  Does pasedBitmap get something real put into it?'

Comment: Got it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-use-break-points-in-eclipse