# Android - Parcel Custom Type - FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I'm developing a Media Player Application where I'm using `ArrayList` to store the list of songs, and want to use that same list between a `Service` and other `Activities`. I've written a custom type Songs implementing `Parcelable` Interface. This is how I did it:

```
     String ID, Title, Artist, Album, Genre, Duration, Path;
        byte[] AlbumArt;

    //constructors go here
        //getters and setters go here    

public Songs(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }
            @Override
                    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dest.writeString(this.ID);
                        dest.writeString(this.Title);
                        dest.writeString(this.Artist);
                        dest.writeString(this.Album);
                        dest.writeString(this.Genre);
                        dest.writeString(this.Duration);
                        dest.writeByteArray(this.AlbumArt);
                        dest.writeString(this.Path);
                    }

                    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        this.ID = in.readString();
                        this.Title = in.readString();
                        this.Artist = in.readString();
                        this.Album = in.readString();
                        this.Genre = in.readString();
                        this.Duration = in.readString();
                        in.readByteArray(this.AlbumArt);
                        this.Path = in.readString();
                    }

                    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Songs> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Songs>() {

                        @Override
                        public Songs createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return new Songs(source); // using parcelable constructor
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Songs[] newArray(int size) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return new Songs[size];
                        }
                    };
```

Now the Problem is I'm getting `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION` when I try to pass the `Arraylist<Songs>` in an Intent. As a workaround I'm using static variables. Any ideas as on how to overcome this solution and pass the `ArrayList<Songs>` in an Intent.

Comment: In this case I have used Global static variables and the problems gone. You can get idea from [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13226397/7608371).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `byte[] AlbumArt`, you are probably exceeding the 1MB IPC limit.

> Any ideas as on how to overcome this solution and pass the ArrayList in an Intent.

I'd start by getting rid of `AlbumArt`. Images should be in an image cache, one designed to make sure that you do not run out of heap space by having a maximum size and getting rid of least-recently-used entries (or moving them to a second-tier disk cache). As a side benefit, moving the `byte[]` out of the `Parcelable` will probably clear up your problem.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that and check.I've come across an ImageLoader library at which I'll take a look. But in general,is my method correct to make that object (with byte[]) Parcelable?

Comment: @PsyGik: "is my method correct to make that object (with byte[]) Parcelable?" -- if by "correct" you mean "will it run, if your `ArrayList<Songs>` is small enough to not hit the 1MB limit", it looks OK. Personally, I am not a big fan of passing whole models around internally this way. IMHO, your models themselves should be a cache, managed by a singleton, and you pass around some IDs or keys or something in `Intent` extras. This saves a chunk of memory and CPU time, as you're not copying and re-copying and re-re-copying and re-re-re-copying and re-re-re-re-copying the same model objects.

Comment: need help on the somewhat similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42062417/6144372