# Getting 'E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 9448080)' while trying to build a notification

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-bitmap

I'm trying to build a notification and receive it after an interval of time.

Here's how:

```
futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 176000;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationG.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationG.NOTIFICATION, getNotification());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), m, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Here's `NotificationG.class`:

```
public class NotificationG extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification_gatsp";
    public static NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mNotifyMgr.notify(5, notification);

    }
}
```

Here's is `getNotification()` method:

```
public Notification getNotification() {

icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.app_icon_1);

        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon_1)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setLargeIcon(icon)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(""))
                        .setContentText("");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ARequest.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        resultIntent.putExtra("text", text);

        // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
        // no need to create an artificial back stack.
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        return mBuilder.build();
    }
```

but I'm not receiving any notification instead this error: `E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 9448080)` is getting printed out.

**What's happening** here and how can I fix it?

Please let me know.

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using (with all those calls to `putExtra("text", text)`? Or is this just an example. It looks like your Notification is 9MB large, which is far too large. What are you putting in the `Intent` as extras?

Comment: @DavidWasser yeah this is actual code but I have replaced the actual key and value with `text`. I'm putting just texts in the `Intent` as extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem here and it was with the small icon of notification. It was exceeding the binder limit.

The same icon was saved in my `mipmap` folder too and changing the reference from `R.drawable.app_icon_1` to `R.mipmap.app_icon_1` did the job for me.

I changed this line:

```
icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.app_icon_1);
```

with this:

```
icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),
            R.mipmap.app_icon_1);
```

and now there is no more error.