# ImageView fullscreen in Activity

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, android-glide

I have a GridView populated with images. When I click on a GridView item it should open a new Activity and show an image in full screen, but it doesn't happen.

I'm using the Glide library. I've tried to debug, but I didn't find the problem.

Any ideas?

Gallery.java

```
  gridViewGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(AdvertisementGallery.this,FullScreenImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",i);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

FullScreenImage.java

```
 viewPager.clearFocus();


        imageItems = Constants.items;


        bitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image");


        //   ImagePageAdapter imagePageAdapter = new ImagePageAdapter(this,imageItems);
        imagePageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,imageItems);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imagePageAdapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(bitmap,false);
```

class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList data){

        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.data.size();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int position = data.indexOf(object);
        return  POSITION_NONE ;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View row = null;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_pager_item_list_layout, container, false);

            //  holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            image = (TouchImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
            row.setTag(image);
        } else {
            image = (ImageView) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = (ImageItem) data.get(position);

       Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(item.getImage())
               .into(image);

        container.addView(row);

        return row;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);


    }
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in this line:         bitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image"); Check what you received from previous activity. Is it maybe null?

Comment: image Position is received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are passing the position of the image. you need to pass the item. instead of position. you need to do following changes in the following way.

in Gallery.java

```
 gridViewGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) data.get(position)

            Intent intent = new Intent(AdvertisementGallery.this,FullScreenImage.class);
            //intent.putExtra("image",i);
            intent.putExtra("imagePosition",i);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Now, Retrieve your image in FullScreenImage.java by following way.

```
imageItems = Constants.items;

int position=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("imagePosition");
ImageItem item = imageItems.get(position);
bitmap = item.getImage();
```

To set in your `ViewPager` you can follow this code:

```
imagePageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,imageItems);
viewPager.setAdapter(imagePageAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
```

And for the issue of

> some time image display and some time is not display in viewpager.

Try to add following line `.placeholder (new ColorDrawable (Color.WHITE))`. so the code looks like :

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(item.getImage())
            .placeholder (new ColorDrawable (Color.WHITE))
           .into(image);
```

And, If you are getting issue only in release mode apk then try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934146/3342570)

Comment: @rahul Can you show me the code of class ImageItem?

Comment: i was tried it but image is not show. i using glide library is not show image in viewpager. when i used universal image loader library its show image in view pager. so, how to image not show through glide library.

Comment: @rahul If you want to load your image as a bitmap, you need to call `asBitmap()` method.  `Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(item.getImage()).asBitmap()
               .into(bitmap);` where bitmap is bitmap of your image.

Comment: i  load image from server url

Comment: @rahul then no need to use `asBitmap` it should load automatically. make sure you have an active internet connection and the URL from which you are loading is proper working. And in none of the above cases, Please check your logcat may be you will find the cause of the problem there.

Comment: @rahul did you got your solution?

Comment: some time image display and some time is not display in viewpager.

Comment: image not show in viewpager is problem solved but above problem is occurred.what i do problem is solved. give, any suggestion. i using Glide library for image load.

Comment: @rahul have you checked your logcat? did you find anything there? or you can refer this link if you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/39336438/3342570 or https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1908

Comment: nothing show in logcat. some  image load in two time gridview tap after load in viewpager.its some image loading issue

Comment: @rahul is it issue for specific images only? have you checked the URL you are trying to load is working? have you checked internet connection?

Comment: in gridview loading perfectly but viewpager load some issue

Comment: @rahul have you tried solutions in the link i mentioned in above comments

Comment: stackoverflow ya github

Comment: @rahul try both one by one. and did you try googling your problem? If not do it now. and still, you did not find any solution then feel free to tell I also will help to try to find out the solution. but, first, you have to search for it on the google

Comment: i have googling my problem after i post on stackoverflow

Comment: @rahul try these links https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2184 or https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/935

Comment: @rahul Did these links were helpful? and feeling pleasure to help you

Comment: i have add placeholder in glide image load issue solved but in a released apk placeholder image is not  display

Comment: is placeholder image is url ?

Comment: placeholder(R.drawable.logo)

Comment: release apk publish on playstore after is not show.

Comment: @rahul do the steps mentioned in my previous post. maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934146/3342570

Comment: @rahul if you find my answer as a helpful one and if it has solved your problem. then please accept my answer.

Comment: don't any response.

Comment: @rahul response of what and by whom?

Answer (score 0):

Check how to send an image from one activity to another activity via intent. In your code,what you are sending is not an image that is a position. How did you get the position in the bitmap? this is not the way. sorry for my english.

check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226263/i-want-to-transfer-the-image-from-one-activity-to-another)

first, convert the image into bitmap then pass bitmap to other activity and receive it.