# Set ImageView Resource and TextView Text from Another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a list view in an activity and when a row is selected I want to show another activity that contains an ImageView and a TextView. How can I set the image and text from the first activity? I'm guessing for the text I can use an extra with the intent.

Comment: you can use the intent also to provide the resource id of the pic you want to show

Comment: you can pass the id of the resource(image) also as an extra in that intent.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles

Answer (score 2):

```
intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)
intent.putExtra("your_string", strName);
```

You can recieve bitmap from another activity like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("data");
```

It costs a lot of memory and is also slow.

If you want to pass it inbetween activities, you can store it in a file. That's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to sending data between Activities

1. you can send image `intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)` and recieve it
   as @deniz suggested
2. you can use Serializable to send data
3. you can create Parcelable and send it to next Activity
4. create a static Bitmap and get it in another Activity but it is not
   a good approach and against OOP