# Android pass Bitmap between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I have seen similar questions to that but most of them show passing bitmap between activities. Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles) question, the accepted answer does not recommend using bundle while passing bitmap between two activities and suggest using intent extras instead. But since i am trying to pass bitmap between fragments, not activities, i cannot use intents and do not know what else to use other than bundle. Here is what i do to pass Bitmap between fragments: I pass bitmap to the activity through an interface, and then pass it to other fragment inside that interface.

```
//MyActivity.java

@Override
public void onMyFragmentFired(Bitmap bitmap) {
    FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    args=new Bundle();
    fragment = MyFragment.newInstance();

    if(bitmap != null){
        args.putParcelable("EXTRA_BITMAP", bitmap);
    }

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    ft.add(fragment, "com.example.myfragment");
    ft.commit();
}
```

I wonder whether i face any problems if bitmap is too large etc. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you keep the reference to your bitmap in `Activity` that hosts you fragments? And then you simply can create a getter for that bitmap, and get it in every fragment, attached to that activity, like this `((MyActivity) getActivity()).getBitmap()`.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer. But could help others.

Another approach that could be tested is converting your Bitmap to a Base64 string. Then you send it to the fragment while you create it.

**Encode the bitmap**

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    String encodedBitmap = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Above code will create a long string that you can use.

Then you can pass it as a bundle argument in the fragments `newInstance()` function.

Then you can decode the string again to get the Bitmap image

**Decoding the image**

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedBitmap, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: Base64 encoded strings take more space on memory than the binary image itself. So please avoid this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the bitmap to the newInstance function.

So you can have

```
Bitmap mBitmap;

public static newInstance(Bitmap b)
{
     mBitmap = b;
}
```

and call the

```
if(bitmap!=null)
{
     fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(bitmap);
}
```

Add a bitmap variable as well in the constructor of your fragment.

Comment: How do reference the non-static field `mBitmap` from a static method `newInstance()`? This will not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to pass the bitmap using [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) and having a shared [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) between fragments as explained in the official docs about [sharing data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing). I do not know if it is the best practice but for my use case it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had lots of issues about passing the data to acitvity or fragment mutually. As a result, I made DataCache pass any object anywhere.

but I've never tried passing Bitmap between Fragments. I think this will work for you. this is super easy example. Gihub : https://github.com/kimkevin/cachepot

**Fragment for Sender**

```
public class FragmentA {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataCache.getInstance().push(yourBitmap);
    }
}
```

**Fragment for Receiver**

```
public class FragmentB {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bitmap yourBitmap = DataCache.getInstance().pop(Bitmap.class);
    }
}
```

try it :D I hope you to help.