# Android pass base64 string to another activity with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, base64

How can I pass a `base64` encoded string to another page. I have tried with this but the program freezes when this code running

```
base64String= base64FromBitmap(capturedImage);
intent.putExtra("BASE64IMAGE", base64String]); // Freezes on this line
```

This is the `base64` `convert` method. It works without problems

```
private static String base64FromBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encoded;
    }
```

Comment: You cant pass large data between activities. I guess there is a 1MB LIMIT. (I READ IT SOMEWHERE)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles

Comment: What you can do is to store it in a file storage and get it back in another activity

Comment: You can get the path of the image and sent that in intent, rather than sending the image in B64

Comment: @RaviGadipudi thank you advice. I suspect in this case. Save the file as I did before, I will send the file path.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the image you are sending is a lot bigger than the intended size of data to be stored in intents.

What I would advise you do instead is save the image to storage, and then get the stored path and send that instead. This will greatly improve the speed, and reduce the chance of corrupting data.

[See this tutorial on how to store the image data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)