# Failed to pass image to another class

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, android-camera

I'm trying to pass an image to another class through `intent`, but **it only works for `captured image`, not for `image selected from gallery`.**

This is where the camera function get started.In **ImageFitScreen.java**, it has a `ok` button used to return back to the previous activity.

**ImageFitScreen.java**

```
 public void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageFitScreen.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");


                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    //pic = f;
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(f) +"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);


                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                }

            }

        });

        builder.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                                 KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    dialog.dismiss();
               finish();
            }

            return true;
        }
        });
        builder.show();



    }



    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                //h=0;
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                        //pic = photo;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    bitmapOptions.inDither = true;
                    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize=8;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
                    Global.img = bitmap;

                    b.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    //p = path;
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {

                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        //pic=file;
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                // h=1;
                //imgui = selectedImage;
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image ******", picturePath + "");
                b.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }




 ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                text=t.getText().toString();
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                b.layout(0, 0, b.getMeasuredWidth(), b.getMeasuredHeight());
                b.buildDrawingCache(true);
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                if (b.getDrawingCache() != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getDrawingCache());
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                    }
                    Global.img = bitmap;
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**Previous Activity**

```
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if(data!=null&&data.hasExtra("text")) {
                    c = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    txt1.setText(c);
                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img); // image can be displayed
                }


            }
            else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
            {

            }
        }

   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // save button
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                a = "Project";
                text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                final int k1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("k");
                returnIntent.putExtra("k1", k1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("c",c);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
```

**The image can be returned to Previous Activity ** since it can display in `viewImage`. In previous activity, it also has a button back to Activity A.

**Activity A**

```
   c = (TextView) claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
     c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                         if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
                                             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditClaims.class);
                                             intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                             intent.putExtra("result", result);
                                             intent.putExtra("description", description);

                                        byte[]data=getBitmapAsByte(getActivity(), Global.img);
                                             intent.putExtra("data",data);
                                             startActivity(intent);

                                             }
                                         else {
                                             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                         }
                                     }
                                         } );

      public static byte[]getBitmapAsByte(final Context context,Bitmap bitmap) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, outputStream);
            return outputStream.toByteArray();

        }

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0);

        if (button == 1) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    description=data.getStringExtra("c");
                    if (Global.img != null) {
                        v.setImageBitmap(Global.img);
                    }

                         as=Long.parseLong(result);
                        c.setText("            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                        break;
  }
        }
       else if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {

        }
```

**Activity B** (Activity)

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("data")) {
           // ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("data"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("data").length);
            viewImage.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
```

**Global.java**

```
public class Global {

    static Bitmap img;
}
```

When it `intent` to Activity B, my app will exit automatically. But it will works if the image is `captured image`. Is it because the size too large? I have no ide on this.Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you have any error log??

Comment: @calvinfly No.. app exit  without given any error

Comment: I follow [this](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/pass-activity-bitmap/) but no success..

Comment: check is data.length>0, you may understand the problem clearer

Comment: @mismanc where to check

Comment: if(data.length>0){intent.putExtra("data",data);
  startActivity(intent);}

Comment: Do you keep the captured image in **Global.img**, too? How do you put it there?

Comment: @AlexCohn `Captured image` and `selected image from gallery` are using same coding

Comment: Sorry, how do you capture the image? Do you use `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent? Do you load the bitmap from `extras.get("data")` in `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: @AlexCohn wait..I editing my post :0

Comment: @AlexCohn I'm sorry if the code are a bit long..Please don't hesitate to tell me if you still don't understand my problem

Comment: Anyone can help? I need help seriously

Comment: you should get the path of the image in `String` variable and pass to next `Activity`, then decode as a `Bitmap` from image path in next `Activity`

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan but why it can display on `viewImage`?

Comment: have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11010565/2311051

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan tried but no luck :(

Comment: Note: for captured image, you use [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) = 8, but for gallery you load the file at full size. That is likely to make the difference.

Comment: As @ZubarAhmadKhan noted [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644614/failed-to-pass-image-to-another-class?noredirect=1#comment55068068_33644614), there is no advantage in passing the huge bitmap via Intent. This mechanism is by no means intended to pass huge data. If you pass the file name, then the consumer activity can choose the best subsampling to fit the view size.

Comment: I've run into two issues with this in the past. 1. Passing images through an Intent is not ideal because of the size limit. I've typically saved the image in shared preferences in the past. 2. I've had an issue before on lollipop where onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) would get back a null or empty data object if the code was selected from gallery. Have you checked to see if data isn't null after you select your image in onActivityResult?

Comment: @Killingsworth ya,it is not null. I wonder why the image can return to previous activity but cannot intent to next activity

Comment: so, are you using the global variable to store the image between activities or are you passing it via the intent as you stated? You should only use one.

Comment: Also, why do you have an onActivityResult in all of these activities? Why do you not just have one for the picture taker activity?

Comment: @Killingsworth I only can use one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put bitmap into Bundle. The best way is saving image on storage and pass path uri between activities.

Answer (score -1):

```
byte [] recieve = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("key",defaultValue);
```

Comment: i already have  `getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("data"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("data").length);` in Activity B