# Setting listView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listView with some items. Every item has a title, picture, and description. Now I'd like to click on particular activity and open new activity, which would be detailed view for particular item. So it needs to have the title and picture from previous activity, and a new, bigger description.

Could someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

For passing images to activities see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4352194/1021581)

likewise you can pass the title & description

```
intent.putExtra("TITLE","title value");
intent.putExtra("DESCRIPTION","Description value")
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not an intent in a traditional way so to say. The problem is that new activity must to automatically take the position of the item in the listview and load proper values. How do I "catch" those values?

Comment: you mean you need to change this item View not starting new activity?!

Comment: no, I mean the program needs to know itself which line was clicked, what position it was, and thus which data should be displayed in new activity. Sorry if I am not clear, I am really new to programming.