# How do I safely exit the Android Camera2BasicFragment and display the captured image in the next activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-camera2

This might be a silly question, but I'm facing problem with safely exiting the `Camera2BasicFragment`.

I've used the sample code from Google to implement the Camera2 API.
[Google Camera2 Sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

Please suggest where exactly I must put the `Intent` for the next activity where I want to display the captured image and make a safe exit from the camera activity.

The camera just freezes, when I try to navigate to the next activity. I tried closing the camera, stopping the background thread. But I'm not doing it right, due to which the screen freezes.

I'm trying to achieve it here. Please let me know if I must do it elsewhere. I've used the sample code, if in case you need to refer the code, use the link mentioned above.

Camera2BasicFragment `ImageSaver` function:

```
private class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

        /**
         * The JPEG image
         */
        private final Image mImage;
        /**
         * The file we save the image into.
         */
        private final File mFile;

        ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                output.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            Bitmap capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            int width = linearLayout.getWidth();
            int height = linearLayout.getHeight();

            int left = width/6;
            int top = height/8;
            Log.e("LEFT TOP", left + " " +top);

            croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(capturedImage, left, top, 5*(width/6), 2*(height/3));

            /**
             * 
             * This is the region of trouble
             * I'm cropping the image and trying to display it in the next activity
             *
             */
            onPause();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class).putExtra("BITMAP", croppedImage));
        }

    }
```

Stack Trace when I try starting the next activity after `ImageSaver()` executes

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdb321004 in tid 21857 (CameraBackgroun)
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the activity on the main thread.

```
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

      startActivity(intent);
  }
 });
```

Shouldn't need to call onPause.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Where exactly do I put the intent?

Comment: No luck. The same exception continues. The camera and thread must be released and closed properly. That is not getting accounted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the bitmap as a parcelable *extra* via **Intent**: it's too big. It's not necessary to [save the bitmap as file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24631097/192373).

The easy way is to use the Application object (which is essentially a singleton on Android) to keep this data for you, but there are alternative patterns for that: [with a `static` field in the first Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311670/192373), or [pass it as a compressed `byteArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890405/192373).

Comment: I'm facing the problem of safely exiting the Fragment. The app crashes. Can you please tell me where can I start the next activity? I tried closing the camera and stopping the background thread once the image is captured, but the app continues to crash.

Comment: As I wrote, the most likely cause of your crash now is that you push too much data into the *extra*. If you have fixed this, but still have a crash, please post the crash trace.

Comment: Even when I just start the activity without any data in the intent, it still crashes. How can I safely close the camera and go to the next activity?

Comment: I've added the stack trace of the exception when I start the next activity after saving the image.

Comment: you must never call lifecycle callbacks yourself. That `onPause()` is enough to ruin your app.

Comment: I fixed it! I used a different method to close the camera and I had to also avoid drawing the overlay when the camera was closed as the width and height of the preview will be unavailable which were necessary for the overlay.