# Displaying an Image in an activity using URI

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application that uses Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) to capture and image. On the process of capturing the image, I noted the output of the image's URI. Right after finishing the camera activity, I wish to display the image using this specific URI.

The method I used to capture images is:

```
    private void saveFullImage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                       "test.jpg");
  outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Which is a method taken from Reto Meier's book Professional  Android 2  Application Development.

The method works fine, and I assume that the URI of the picture I just took is stored in the outputFileUri variable. Then at this point of the code is where I want to display the picture:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {

      //I want to display the picture I just took here
      //using the URI

  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried creating a new layout object and a new ImageView object using the method setImageURI(outputFileUri). My main layout (xml) did not have a ImageView object. But even when I set the contentView to the new layout with the ImageView attached to it, it doesn't display anything. I tried creating a Bitmap object from the URI and set it to the ImageView, but I get an unexpected error and forced exit.

I have seen examples from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227209/how-to-get-the-images-from-device-in-android-java-application/2229154#2229154) which creates a Bitmap from URI, but it's not displaying it?

My question is just how to display an image in the middle of a running activity? Do I need to get the File Path (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/android-get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)) in order to display it? If I make a Bitmap out of the URI, how do I display the Bitmap?

I'm just probably missing something simple...so any help would be a greatly appreciated!

Also additional question for thought: If I were to take multiple pictures, would you recommend me to use the SimpleCursorAdapter instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This question is for long time ago. I hope this answer help somebody who has same question.
I just test this code and it works fine.

java code :

```
package com.mywebsite.mohammad.openfiledialog;
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.net.Uri;   
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView ImageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Intent intent = new Intent()
                .setType("image/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 123);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==123 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedfile = data.getData(); //The uri with the location of the file
            ImageView.setImageURI(selectedfile);
        }
    }
}
```

xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You create a Bitmap out of the URI
2. You create a new instance of BitmapDrawable passing in the Bitmap
3. You add the BitmapDrawable to a Window (setBackgroundDrawable),
   View (setBackgroundDrawable)] or ImageView (setImageDrawable)

Comment: Alright, will try and get the results back here soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct way of doing it:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```