# Get bitmap from URI

Tags: xamarin.android

I am selecting image from a gallery.
This is the code which i am using

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SelectPicture);
```

I am getting this string in `data.DataString` `content://media/external/images/media/11` on Activty result..
Which is not a full path to the selected Image. But ultimately i want to convert it to bitmap.

In activity result..

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)

Bitmap bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
```

Gives null error.

How ever instead of selecting image from the gallery when i capture image from camera it works fine and i get the bitmap. Code i am using:

```
 var cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
 cameraIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, imageUri);
 this.StartActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TakePicture);
```

Answer (score 7):

To convert from Uri to Bitmap follow this example: [convertUriToBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227209/how-to-get-the-images-from-device-in-android-java-application/2229154#2229154).
In monodroid the code is as follows:

```
private Android.Graphics.Bitmap NGetBitmap(Android.Net.Uri uriImage)
    {
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap mBitmap = null;
         mBitmap = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, uriImage);
         return mBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recipe:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/Data/Files/Selecting_a_Gallery_Image

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri uri = data.Data;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Android

`val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(contentResolver.openInputStream(uri))`

Xamarin Android

```
var ins = context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitamp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(ins);
```