# How to add pictures from the gallery into the component 'Gallery' in ANDROID?

Tags: android, gallery, image-gallery

I need a example of how to add a 'X' number of pictures of the gallery into a component 'gallery' in ANDROID develop.

Please show me a simple example (it's for my personal knowledge).
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://www.androidinterview.com/android-gallery-view-example-displaying-a-list-of-images/, you can see an example of show images in a android gallery component using local images, if you want show images from device's gallery, then you can see this:

[how to get the images from device in android java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227209/how-to-get-the-images-from-device-in-android-java-application)